# Upload file to payara5 docroot

Tags: java, payara

I've installed payara5 on ubuntu and going to upload file to `docroot`.i need to know if there is such a capability in payara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payara doesn't support uploading individual files. It's an application server and supports only uploading whole application packages.

But you can upload files to the docroot manually, e.g. using FTP or SFTP. If you place your files to `glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot`, they will be served from the root context. E.g., if you upload a file image.jpg to that directory, it will be accessible at http://host:8080/image.jpg